# push notification Handling when app is not running / call a url if push receive the app

Tags: url, callback, apple-push-notifications, push

i have a question. I have configured my app for development push notifications and all was working fine.
All push notifications arrived the app on the device. But i want to handle the push notification in a special way. If my app is running or in background the function

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

will work fine. But is the app killed the function doesn't work. I need a idea to handle incomming push notifications whether if the app is running, in background or killed. If a push was received the app must call a callback URL. if there any way to realize this?

for example i send the following apn string:

```
{"aps":{"content-available":1,"alert":"This","badge":1},"callback":"https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/sf/daniel_push/985270815/12323453534534/?device(id)=1111111111&s="}
```

At the end all what i want is to call the callback url if the app becomes a push notification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in didFinishLaunching:

```
NSDictionary *userData = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if (userData) {
    // handle notification
}
```

Comment: this is for the handling if the app is startet. but i need a handler when the push comes on the device and the app is killed, and the user did not respond.